# How to structure models in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(3) in which I have to create some models to store reports. There are 4 different models to represents each type of report with only 2 common fields(`RequestId`, `InstCode`) but the rest of the fields are different. In the end, I have to display the 10 recent reports (mixed from all models) on the home page.

Here's how I have implemented my models at the moment:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class DistributionReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    InstCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    Denomination = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Distribution Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class ExpenditureReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    InstCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    StaffExpenditure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    Month = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    Quarter = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Expenditure Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class StorageReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    InstCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    Denomination = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Processing Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class AssetsReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    InstCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    AssetClassificationId = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    VaultCapacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    HalfOftheYear = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Assets Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId
```

What is the best way to structure these models, so I can query the recent reports ( It can be of any type)?

Comment: I can see 2 possibilities: 1) Creating a base report class that uses [generic foreign relations](https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/#generic-foreign-key) to the different report models or 2) model inheritance with [django polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

Look into how normalization works, since all models have 2 common fields lets say you have a table called Report and it has the fields `RequestId` and `InstCode`. Now all your other models can be said to be in a `XYZReport is a Report` kind of relationship.
You can achieve this using a OneToOne Field like so:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    InstCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    DISTRIBUTION = 'DI'
    EXPENDITURE = 'EX'
    STORAGE = 'ST'
    ASSETS = 'AS'
    REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (DISTRIBUTION, 'Distribution Report'),
        (EXPENDITURE, 'Expenditure Report'),
        (STORAGE, 'Storage Report'),
        (ASSETS, 'Assets Report'),
    ]
    report_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=DISTRIBUTION,
    )
    # Any more common fields

class DistributionReport(models.Model):
    report = models.OneToOneField(
        Report,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'distribution_report'
    )
    # Other fields

# Other Report models in similar fashion
```

Now whenever making an object of any kind of report also make an object of `Report` and assign it to report attribute of the models. Save both the models, also to figure out what kind of report an instance of Report is add the relevant report_type to the report instance like so:

```
report.report_type = Report.DISTRIBUTION # In case of Distribution Report
```

To figure out whether an instance of Report is of a particular type:

```
report.report_type == report.DISTRIBUTION # will get whether Report is a DistributionReport
```

To get the specific types object use the related_name set in the OneToOne Field:

```
distribution_report = report.distribution_report
```